# Screen and mouse pointer acting weirdly in adobe apps

Tags: windows, display, mouse, adobe-photoshop, windows-11

Please check this video - https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/vvtl93/mouse_pointer_acting_weirdly_on_adobe_apps/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

As you can see, when I click the eraser screen goes insane. I have tried almost every possible solutions including drive update, reinstalling PS, installing different version even changing the mouse pointer icon. But after some time this issue poped up in the MS office application. Any of you guys ever experienced this kind of problem. I can't even understand how to google this problem. Please help me.

P.S. - At first time I recorded this using screen recorder. But surprisingly in the record this flickering this don't appear (it was a clean video). I have no idea what's going on.

Still from video…

[image]

mini-gif for if original video ever breaks…

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is that if it appears on screen but not in a screen recording, then it's a hardware fault.
GPU dying.

Adobe apps use Open GL is a particularly aggressive manner. Try disabling or reducing the GPU dependence in Prefs > Performance to reduce the OpenGL 'load'.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My laptop is quite new and have Nvidia MX330 adapter. And one thing I noticed that this thing also occurs when I try to change the size of the cursor size. I don't know what's the connection between them.

Comment: That's a low-end GPU, a 2020 re-badge of a 2017 design. Try knocking back the GPU-dependency as above & see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

If one can't see something on the recording what one actually can see on the screen and it is for example such blinks it means that the troubles aren't in the app.

Most Adobe programs are hard for PC and PS is one of the hardest. Maybe your PC is not able to work nice in it? For example, in my last laptop when I was using AE the app did not see any clicks I did and sometimes I had visual bugs with it, but the PC is still working nice, just not in Adobe programs (I'm also able to use it in games, so it is fine).

It also may mean that the problem is not just in system requirements. Something may go on with your PC parts. Is it old?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My laptop is quite new and have Nvidia MX330 gpu. And when only working with photoshop and MS office app, I got this problem.

Comment: So I can only guess it is drivers versions problem if your PC is enough for the requirements. Or PS's version.